# How to play youtube video in between two time intervals in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube

I have a [YouTube video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zv-Uvo_Kq8) ...with duration 4:04

I want to play the YouTube video from 2:05 to 2:35 video only..

I googled and found to [play video from certain time](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zv-Uvo_Kq8#t=2m5s).

**Source is**: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1206-how-to-link-to-a-specific-point-in-a-youtube-video/

But I requirement is to play between two time intervals..

I am playing YouTube video using webview..Here is my code.

```
NSString *youTubeVideoPlayWebUrl1=@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zv-Uvo_Kq8";

NSString *embedHTML=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"width=320.0 height=200.0></embed></body></html>",youTubeVideoPlayWebUrl1];
NSLog(@"my embedhtml string is %@",embedHTML);

[WebView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

The resulting URL would be something like this: http://www.youtube.com/v/6zv-Uvo_Kq8?version=3&start=125&end=155&autoplay=1&hl=en_US&rel=0

Taken from http://www.techtipsforall.com/youtube-help/embed-part-of-youtube-video-from-specific-start-time-to-end-time/

Answer (score 0):

To do it on an embedded video, use the “start” parameter in html of embedded video

[Read this for detailed explanation](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/start-youtube-video-minutes-seconds/)

Comment: I already referred above link...I tried with below.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zv-Uvo_Kq8=en_US&start=100&end=200
But it is playing from first only....Have I go wrong anywhere..@Lithu